# Object is not iterable in Django while returning objects to API

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django rest framework and Django to create a website showing events.
I'm filtering my existing models in the database and outputting the new objects in a new API. So far I am returning all objects in the database while returning the filtered objects cases this error: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable.

**In models.py** Here you're seeing that I don't actually filter by date. Instead, I'm testing the code by filtering on status.

```
from django.db import models

class EventQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def today(self):
        return self.filter(status="Publish")


class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return EventQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def today(self):
        return self.get_queryset().today()

class Event(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Smiles', 'Smiles'),
        ('Laughter', 'Laughter'),
        ('Crazy', 'Crazy'),
        ('Food', 'Food'),
        ('Outside', 'Outside'),
    )
    STATUS = (
        ('Publish', 'Publish'),
        ('Draft', 'Draft'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    startDate = models.DateField(blank=True)
    endDate = models.DateField(blank=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=CATEGORY)

    objects = models.Manager()
    date = EventManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'link')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Using python manage.py shell to test the query works and outputs the correct objects. Here is an example of some of the data that I'm getting:

```
<EventQuerySet [<Event: Positivus Festival 2022>, Central European zone stage in equestrian show jumping "Rīga 2022" >, <Event: Exhibition Dramaturgy of the Landscape>, <Event: Writing Implements of Medieval Riga>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

**Here are my views.py file** I've been following [this official documentantion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/).

```
from events.models import Event
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView 
from events.serializers import EventSerializer
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class EventTodayView(ListAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows events to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Event.date.today()

class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    title = filters.CharFilter(field_name="title", lookup_expr='contains')
    startDate = filters.DateFilter(field_name="startDate", lookup_expr='gte')
    endDate = filters.DateFilter(field_name="endDate", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'status', 'startDate', 'endDate']


class EventAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows events to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Event.objects.all().order_by('startDate')
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = EventFilter
```

**And this is my urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from events import views

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', views.EventAPIView.as_view(), name='api'),
    path('api/today', views.EventTodayView.as_view(), name='api-today')
]
```

**Full error message is here:**

```
Internal Server Error: /api/today
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 199, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 38, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "D:\Prosjekter\Koding\What's happening\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 149, in filter_queryset
    for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: The error is telling you that `self.filter_backends` is a class (a 'type' object) rather than something iterable, like a tuple. Have you truncated the traceback?  It doesn't show any lines from your own code, but some of it must be in there somewhere

Comment: Assuming the relevant class is `EventTodayView` because url is `/api/today` then let's see the DRF src: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py#L193 and https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py#L43 ...so `filter_backends = api_settings.DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS` ...check the value of `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS` in your django settings

Comment: Hey @Anentropic :) Thank you so much for helping out. The error happened because of a line I had put in for django filters. In settings.py: 



    `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Code underneath caused the error 
    DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend')
    }`

I removed it, and both my APIs seems to be working well. I see my mistake was to set the Django Filter as [default](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/rest_framework.html#quickstart). Thank you!

Comment: I think this is missing the trailing comma to turn it into a tuple: `'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend')` ... should be `'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)`